# Can I let people use a different Tensorflow-gpu version above what they had installed with different CUDA dependencies?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was trying to pack and release a project which uses `tensorflow-gpu`. Since my intention is to make the installation as easy as possible, I do not want to let the user compile `tensorflow-gpu` from scratch so I decided to use `pipenv` to install whatsoever version pip provides.

I realized that although everything works in my original local version, I can not `import tensorflow` in the virtualenv version.

`ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Although this seems to be easily fixable by changing local symlinks, that may break my local `tensorflow` and is against the concept of `virtualenv` and I will not have any idea on how people installed CUDA on their instances, so it doesn't seems to be promising for portability.

What can I do to ensure that `tensorflow-gpu` works when someone from internet get my project only with the guide of "install CUDA X.X"? Should I fall back to `tensorflow` to ensure compatibility, and let my user install `tensorflow-gpu` manually?

Comment: No symlinks. Use LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: @Patwie The core problem is that I won't know where the user would have installed CUDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a working tensorflow-gpu on a machine does involve a series of steps including installation of cuda and cudnn, the latter requiring an NVidia approval. There are a lot of machines that would not even meet the required config for tensorflow-gpu, e.g. any machine that doesn't have a modern nvidia gpu. You may want to define the tensorflow-gpu requirement and leave it to the user to meet it, with appropriate pointers for guidance. If the  project can work acceptably on tensorflow-cpu, that would be a much easier fallback option.